# Realm doesn't support this field type: Companion

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, realm-java

I'm facing off an issue due to companion object inside a Realm entity.

Example:

```
// Entity
open class MyEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String? = "",
    // other fields...
): RealmObject() {

    companion object{
        fun clean(realm: Realm) {
            realm.beginTransaction()
            realm.where(MyEntity::class.java).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm()
            realm.commitTransaction()
        }
    }
}

// Migration code
schema
        .create(MyEntity.class.getSimpleName())
        .addField("id", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY);

addMissingFields(schema, MyEntity.class);
```

When migration is executed, I get the following exception:

`Realm doesn't support this field type: Companion(class com.example.MyEntity$Companion)`

I'd like to know how ignore the `companion object` from Realm scan.

Comment: I had similar problem with kotlin companion object, @Ignore annotation seems not to work with methods. So What I did was,  I move the method in the companion object outside the class but in the same file then remove the companion object block. Everything seems to work fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Realm's annotation `@Ignore`.